# How to make an image able to be spun

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an image of a circle which is able to be spun when the user slides down or up.

[image: Image of what i want]

But of course it's a continues spin.

I'm sorry if this is vague, please comment if you want me to change it!

Comment: any code from your side?

Comment: No sir, i dont have anycode at the momement its just an idea/image.

Comment: Check this. it may help you to spin image: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137490/how-to-spin-an-android-icon-on-its-center-point